# Sort vector of objects using TWO criteria

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

Let's say I have `vector<People*> Population` with

```
class People {
    string name;
    string city;
    int id;
};
```

and I'd like to sort first by `name` and then by `city`, for example:

```
Anna, Alabama, 1284
Anna, New York, 8377
Daniel, Sydney, 8332
Peter, Alabama, 6392
Peter, Munich, 5590
```

I was thinking I would first sort by `name`, then sort by `city` within a `name` and then move onto the next `name`.

Is there a better way though?

Comment: You can sort in one go as long as you use a precondition, that takes both fields into consideration.

Comment: Any reason why you're using `vector<People*>` instead of `vector<People>`?

Comment: If I understood correctly, for sorting it's better to have a vector of pointers so I don't have to move the whole object and instead just swap pointers.

Comment: @HichigayaHachiman -- Better to have another vector of indices, not pointers, and swap the indices.  Pointers add another level of complexity that you don't need to get into.

Comment: Also the pointers typically result in memory scattered around whatever pool it came from not in one nice contiguous block, robbing you of the caching and prediction advantages that make `vector` lightning fast on a modern processor. Whatever advantages you got from the quicker sort using pointers is quickly eaten up by the added cost when iterating. Similar to what happens with linked lists.

Comment: Side note; With a stable sorting algorithm you could first sort by city and then in a second run (over all entries) by name.

Comment: @HichigayaHachiman In addition to that, swapping `People` during the sort would more than likely call the `swap` for the `std::string` items, which could be optimized to just swapping two pointers and an int by the compiler.  So basically you're not buying anything by using pointers, and instead inheriting more headaches maintaining these pointers properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass a custom comparator to [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

```
std::sort(Population.begin(), Population.end(), [](People* a, People* b) {
    if (a->name != b->name) return a->name < b->name;
    return a->city < b->city;
});
```

Comment: Dang it you beat me too it!

Comment: Could you please explain what `[](People* a, People* b)` means? First time I've seen something like this.

Comment: `[](…) { … }` is the syntax for a [__lambda__](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), aka function literal, aka closure.

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize `std::tuple`'s comparison:

```
std::sort(Population.begin(), Population.end(),
    [](auto& p1, auto& p2) {
        return std::tie(p1->name, p1->city) < std::tie(p2->name, p2->city); 
    });
```

This way you can add more fields for sorting very easily.